# How to use myst-parser for SharePoint web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts, myst

I tried to include myst-parser as external JavaScript library for a SharePoint WebPart, following

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries#reference-existing-libraries-as-external-resources

```
  "externals": {
    "myst-parser": {
      "path": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/myst-parser@1.0.21/dist/myst.min.js",
      "globalName": "myst-parser"
    }
  },
```

In my webpart:

```
import * as myst from 'myst-parser';
const html = myst.mystParse('# Hello to the world!')
```

I am able to server the web part. However, it shows

[image]

=> How to correctly include myst-parser in Sharepoint?

**Related:**

https://github.com/executablebooks/mystmd/issues/824#issuecomment-1880858355

[How to use unified.js in sharepoint web part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850612/how-to-use-unified-js-in-sharepoint-web-part/77862518#77862518)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade to downgrade the version of unified and adapt gulpfile.js to include a custom webpack configuration.

Content of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "component-webpart",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0 || >=18.17.1 <19.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.106.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-component-base": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.18.2",
    "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "3.15.1",
    "@pnp/telemetry-js": "2.0.0",
    "devlop": "1.1.0",
    "marked": "11.1.0",
    "myst-parser": "1.0.21",
    "myst-to-html": "1.0.21",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "rehype-stringify": "9.0.3",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "unified": "10.0.1" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7": "0.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.18.2",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@types/marked": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "@types/unist": "3.0.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.18.4",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "webpack": "5.89.0"
  }
}
```

Content of gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');


build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
  var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);

  result.set('serve', result.get('serve-deprecated'));

  return result;
};


build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
  additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
    generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(
      {
        resolve: {
          alias: {   
            'myst-parser': 'myst-parser/dist',                      
            'myst-common': 'myst-common/dist',
            'myst-directives': 'myst-directives/dist',
            'myst-frontmatter': 'myst-frontmatter/dist',
            'myst-roles': 'myst-roles/dist',
            'myst-spec': 'myst-spec/dist',
            'myst-spec-ext': 'myst-spec-ext/dist',
            'myst-to-html': 'myst-to-html/dist',
            'myst-transforms': 'myst-transforms/dist',
            'markdown-it-amsmath': 'markdown-it-amsmath/dist',           
            'markdown-it-dollarmath': 'markdown-it-dollarmath/dist',           
            'markdown-it-myst': 'markdown-it-myst/dist',
            'markdown-it-myst-extras': 'markdown-it-myst-extras/dist',   
          },
        },
      }
    );

    return generatedConfiguration;
  }
});

build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

Example usage:

```
import {unified} from 'unified';
import { mystParser } from 'myst-parser';
import { State, transform, mystToHast, formatHtml  } from 'myst-to-html';
import rehypeStringify from 'rehype-stringify';

//...

let htmlString = '!! Could not render markdown content with MyST !!:\n' + markdownContent;

  try{
    const pipe = unified()
    .use(mystParser)
    .use(transform, new State())     
    .use(mystToHast)
    .use(formatHtml)
    .use(rehypeStringify);

    const result = pipe.processSync(markdownContentWithLinks);
    htmlString = result.value;   
  } catch(error){
    console.log('Could not render markdown content with MyST!', error);
  }    

  return (   
    <div 
      className={styles.component}
      title={extraSearchTerms}       
      data-source={url} 
    >   
    <div
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:htmlString}}
    >
    </div>      
    </div>      
  );
```